# Get Specific Value From Json array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm Try To Access Some specific Value From Return JSON
Real Value is `79#45#597#10#10#10000#M`

```
$retframe = str_ireplace('#',',', $stframe);
echo json_encode(array( 'Value' => $retframe));
///Output Response Back is 
{"Value":"79,45,597,10,10,10000,M"}
```

I Want to Get Only Value of `79,597,10`

Comment: `explode()` your string and get the first 3 slices with `array_slice()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the 1st, 3rd and 5th number of $stframe

```
$stframe = '79#45#597#10#10#10000#M';
list($p1,$p2,$p3,$p4,$p5,$p6,$p7) = explode('#',$stframe);
$retframe = $p1 . ',' . $p3 . ',' . $p5;
echo json_encode(array( 'Value' => $retframe));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get 79,597,10 values statically than you will do it like this way.

```
$retframe = str_ireplace('#',',', $stframe);//$retframe = '79,45,597,10,10,10000,M';
$rs = explode(",",$retframe);
$array[] = $rs[0];
$array[] = $rs[2];
$array[] = $rs[3];
$array1= implode(",", $array);
echo json_encode(array( 'Value' => $array1));
```

and you will get result like this : {"Value":"79,597,10"}